# Angular 2 router Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am getting the following error when trying to use the router in angular 2:
[Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcv4D.png) and I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Any help is really appreciated.

I have the following files

***main.ts***

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from'angular2/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { NotesComponent } from './notes.component';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `
  <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
  <nav>
   <a [routerLink]="['Login']">Login</a>
   <a [routerLink]="['Notes']">Notes</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
 directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
 providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@RouteConfig([
 {
   path: '/login',
   name: 'Login',
   component: LoginComponent,
   useAsDefault: true
 },
 {
  path: '/notes',
  name: 'Notes',
  component: NotesComponent
 }
])

export class AppComponent{
 title = 'Angular 2 test';
}
```

***login.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
 selector: 'login',
 template: `<h1>Login Test</h1>`
})
export class LoginComponent {

}
```

***notes.component.ts***

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
 selector: 'notes',
 template: `<h1>Notes Test</h1>`
})
export class NotesComponent {

}
```

Comment: What browser? What Angular version?

Comment: version 2.0.0-beta.15 in google chrome.

Comment: do shift `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` from `AppComponent` to `bootstrap` function with `HashLocationStrategy`

Comment: Do you use minified scripts, try unminified or beta.16

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer just tried beta.16 and it works, thank you. However, I don't understand why this solved the problem so can you please explain why? I was following the online tutorial a few days ago and beta.16 wasn't there yet.

Comment: Beta.16 was just released an minified sripts are broken since beta.1

Comment: Okay. Thanks again @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known issue since beta.1.Either use unminified scripts or update to beta.16