# EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am an Angular2 newbie. When I try to add this code into camp.detail.component.html (for detail/:id API view),

```
{{campDetail.campground.name}}
```

it always appears the following error message:

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

When I remove

```
{{campDetail.campground.name}}
```

then there is no error message, and we can see the object is printed in the console:

[image: error3]

I did many searches and tried as many solutions as possible but still find no proper way to solve this problem. (e.g: [Angular 2 router Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896081/angular-2-router-error-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property) , [Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot read property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507581/uncaught-in-promise-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined) , [Angular 2 Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isActivated' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954459/angular-2-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-isactivated-o) , https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8519 )

How do I solve this exception? Any suggestion will be helpful and useful for me. I really appreciate it.

My files are below:

*campgrounds.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Campground } from "../models/campground";
import { Comment } from "../models/comment";

export class CampDetail {
    campground: Campground;
    comments: Comment[];
}

@Injectable()
export class CampgroundService {
    private campgroundsUrl = 'api/campground';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getCamps(): Promise<Campground[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.campgroundsUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getCamp(id: number): Promise<CampDetail> {
        return this.http.get(this.campgroundsUrl + '/' + id)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); 
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

*campground.ts*

```
export class Campground {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    image: string;
    description: string;
    username: string;
    user_id: number;
}
```

*comment.ts*

```
export class Comment {
    id: number;
    text: string;
    campground_id: number;
    username: string;
    user_id: number;
}
```

*camp.detail.component.ts*

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import { CampgroundService, CampDetail } from "../../services/campgounds.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'campDetail',
    templateUrl: './app/components/campgrounds/camp.detail.component.html'
})

export class CampDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    error: any;
    campDetail: CampDetail = new CampDetail();

    constructor(
        private campgroundService: CampgroundService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => this.campgroundService.getCamp(params['id']))
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.campDetail = data;
                console.log(this.campDetail);
            });
    }
}
```

*campground.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CampgroundService } from "../../services/campgounds.service";
import { Campground } from "../../models/campground";

@Component({
    selector: 'camps',
    templateUrl: './app/components/campgrounds/campgrounds.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/components/campgrounds/campgrounds.component.css']
})

export class CampgroundsComponent implements OnInit {
    camps: Campground[];

    constructor(private router: Router, private campService: CampgroundService) { }

    getCamps() {
        this.campService.getCamps().then(camps => this.camps = camps);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getCamps();
    }

    gotoDetail(id: number) {
        this.router.navigate(['/detail', id]);
    }
}
```

The weird thing is when I call the campground API using getCamps() in campground.component, everything works properly. After clicking the button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="gotoDetail(camp.id)"> More Info </button>
```

and directing to another page, I will get this error.

Answer (score 4):

Since your `campDetail` data is loaded asynchronously, and isn't available at the time the component is created, you need to check its nested properties' path using the [Angular safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator):

```
{{campDetail?.campground?.name}}
```

Comment: It works properly now!!! Really appreciate it. I spent my whole day trying to solve this problem...